# Enforce type on value to callback inside callback in d.ts file

Tags: typescript, callback

I have jQuery plugin that have prompt function that accept callack function  with setPrompt as the only parameter:

the code look like this:

```
obj.prompt(function(setPrompt) {
   setPrompt(10);
});
```

is it possible to enforce the parameter to setPrompt, in d.ts file, to be string so it show error when passing 10 without user add type to that callback.

in my d.ts file I have:

```
type setStringFunction = (value: string) => void;
type cmdPrompt = (setPrompt: setStringFunction) => void;
interface Cmd extends JQuery {
    prompt(cmdPrompt): Cmd;
    prompt(): cmdPrompt;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already does what you want it to, you just have a small error, you specify `prompt(cmdPrompt)` which means a function with a parameter named `cmdPrompt` not a parameter of type `cmdPrompt`. You just need to change that to `param: cmdPrompt` and all will work as expected

```
type setStringFunction = (value: string) => void;
type cmdPrompt = (setPrompt: setStringFunction) => void;
interface Cmd extends JQuery {
    prompt(param: cmdPrompt): Cmd;
    prompt(): cmdPrompt;
}

let obj!: Cmd;

obj.prompt(function(setPrompt) {
    setPrompt(10); // error
});
```